# Forgot password but browser saved login

Tags: support, login, stack-exchange-openid, password

I've saved my Stack Exchange login credentials on my phone.

However, due to how much different passwords I use for multiple sites, I've forgot them. Additionally, I'm unable to access the my logins page at all on mobile.

To add to the mess, the email address I use for Stack Exchange is basically used for just that, and rarely used for anything else or opened (it isn't my main email, that's why), so I forgot that password too.

Knowing this, what can I do to change my password and email that are registered to my Stack Exchange profile?

Comment: Click "full site" in the bottom. You then will be able to access the "my logins" page and add a new login.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard When I access my network profile, it already shows the desktop version of the site on its own. And on that page, pressing the "my logins" button does nothing. Same thing if I try to press "update profile info"

Comment: You must visit this on an actual site, e.g. here on MSE. Adding on one site will affect all sites.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, thanks, I can access my profile settings page now. However, when I try to remove my login info to add a new one, I can't because there is only one. When I try to add a new login, it asks to connect my new login to another service like Google or facebook or some other OpenID provider, and I don't want that, I want a normal stack exchange account.

Comment: hmm... not sure it applies for your case,  but try following the steps mentioned [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114704/152859).

Comment: @shadowizard Thanks. After I do that, can I remove my old email address?

Comment: If you succeed adding a new login sure, you can safely remove any other.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Thank you *very* ***very*** much for your help, I have now restored access to my account!! Do I delete this question now, or do I keep it and edit it as solved?

Comment: Awesome! Please post a self answer, explaining what you did, so that others with this issue will be able to get the help they need. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're logged in to your Stack Exchange account, but do not remember what your password was, nor do you remember your email's password either, here's what you can do:

1. Create a new email address, or find another email address you already have that you wish to use to login to Stack Exchange with. Don't choose the same email address you don't know the password of.
2. On the Stack Exchange website you're on `https://SomeSite.stackexchange.com`, visit your profile page. On the desktop Stack Exchange website, your profile can be accessed by clicking on your avatar icon in the top right of the webpage.

The format of the link will be like this:

`https://SomeSite.stackexchange.com/users/Your-User-ID-Number-Here/Your-Username-Here`

3. On that profile page, visit your "*edit profile and settings*" tab:

`https://SomeSite.stackexchange.com/users/edit/Your-User-ID-Number-Here`

4. Scroll down, and you'll see the heading:

`Private information (not shown publicly)`

Below this heading, there is a text box for email. Change the email within this text box to the email that you picked in your mind in the first step.

5. Below this, you'll find two blue buttons:

`Save changes just for this community` and `Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities`

Click on any one of them.

6. On that same Stack Exchange website, `https://SomeSite.stackexchange.com`, visit the account recovery page:

   `https://SomeSite.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery`

   Type the email address you chose in the first step.
7. Open the recovery email you'll get in that email address, and follow the instructions within it to change your password.
8. Once you've changed your password, return to your profile page again, this time on the vertically arranged list of tabs, click on the `My Logins` tab.

   `https://SomeSite.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/Your-User-ID-Number-Here`

   From there, you'll see your list of logins, and a "*remove*" button to the right of each one of them.

   Delete your old email address login from there, if you wish.